# Sql join 2 tables with userId outside

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE event (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   city VARCHAR ( 30 ),
   author_id INT REFERENCES users (id) NOT NULL,
   text VARCHAR,
   cDate TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
   uDate TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);


CREATE TYPE InviteStatus AS ENUM ('pending', 'approved', 'declined');
CREATE TABLE invite  (
   sender_id INT REFERENCES users (id) NOT NULL,
   receiver_id INT REFERENCES users (id) NOT NULL,
   event_id INT REFERENCES event (id) NOT NULL,
   receiver_approved InviteStatus DEFAULT 'pending' NOT NULL,
   cDate TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
   uDate TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

We have 2 tables. We get userId which is sender_id. We need get all columns from **event** and create field receiver_approved from **invite** in our results, if userId = sender_id as paramter from outside exists in **invite** table and event.id = invite.event_id

Comment: You should always identify the flavour of RDBMS you are asking about. I have added postrgressql which is what your question seems to relate to

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.*, i.receiver_approved
FROM invite i
JOIN event e on e.id = i.event_id
WHERE i.sender_id = :userID
```

where `userID` is a parameter from outside